# MVC Bundling - one file in more than one bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have 5 js files:

1. a1.js
2. a2.js
3. a3.js
4. a4.js
5. a5.js

bundled together in **bundle1.js**, and I'm using this bundle in `View1`.

Now I need to use **a3.js , a5.js** and **a6.js** in in `View2`.

Can I create a new bundle with **a3, a5** and **a6** or use bundle1 for **a3 & a5** and create new bundle for **a6**?

Which is the good approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that there's no correct answer to this. You could also consider including `a6.js` in `bundle1` and just using `bundle1.js` in `View2`. It will already be cached by the browser, so no additional HTTP requests even if some of the individual js are not needed. So basically have all your scripts in a single bundle that is placed in your Layout even if not strictly required by all views.

But if you have to choose between creating a new bundle with a3, a5 and a6 or bundle1 for a3 & a5 and create new bundle for a6 then the first is preferred.

Comment: bundle1 is used in most of the views.i.e, it is a common bundle. but a6 is needed only in view2. then is it good idea to include a6 in bundle1.?

Comment: Yeah, just put it in the bundle and reuse this bundle everywhere.

Comment: Then, a6/js will be downloaded unnecessarly in all other pages right.?

Comment: No, it will be downloaded only once. That's the whole point of bundling -> combine and minify all your javascript resources into a single file which you reference. Once this bundle is downloaded on the client browser, on subsequent pages it is no longer downloaded. On the other hand if you make multiple different bundles that you link in your pages then it will be worse because even if they are smaller in size, they will have to be fetched which means additional HTTP requests to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bundle1 for all view. But problem is that when some browser is going to open your page which required only a3.js and a5.js then it will download all. and it makes your site very slow.

So, according to me, you should always create multiple bundling as per required js/css as per page.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JqueryInterviewHomePage").Include("~/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "~/Content/Jquery/bootstrap.min.js", "~/Content/Jquery/InterviewHomeJquery.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JqueryInterviewViewPage").Include("~/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "~/Content/Jquery/bootstrap.min.js", "~/Content/Jquery/SingleInterviewPostJquery.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JqueryArticlesHomePage").Include("~/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js","~/Content/Jquery/bootstrap.min.js", "~/Content/Jquery/ArticlesHomeJquery.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JqueryArticlesViewPage").Include("~/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js","~/Content/Jquery/bootstrap.min.js", "~/Content/Jquery/SinglePostJquery.js"));
```

Hope this will help you.
thanks